# MySQL - querying 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have 3 tables, each with a field `foo`. How do I get the following records:

1. All records where the value of foo exist in all 3 tables?
2. All records where the value of foo exist in any 2 tables?
3. All records where the value of foo exist in 1 table only?

`foo` is UNIQUE.

**My attempt for #1:**

```
SELECT a.foo
FROM   a
WHERE  a.foo IN (SELECT b.foo
                 FROM   b
                 WHERE  b.foo IN (SELECT c.foo
                                  FROM   c))
```

For #2, I think I need to do something similar to #1, but for 2 tables at a time {a,b}, {b,c}, {a,c} - and then UNION it? Not sure.

For #3, no clue.

**UPDATE: Sample Data**

```
Table1
 - foo-a
 - foo-b
 - foo-c

Table2
 - foo-a
 - foo-b

Table3
 - foo-a
 - foo-c
 - foo-d
```

For #1 question, there is 1 record that exist in all 3 tables: foo-a. For #2 question, there are 2 records that exist in 2 tables: foo-b (in Table1 and Table2) and foo-c (in Table1 and Table3). For #3 question, there is 1 record that exist in only 1 table: foo-d.

Comment: can you show smple data?

Comment: Do you just want the data from table `a`, or do you want all related rows?

Comment: What do you mean by exist in all 2 tables? and exist in all 1 table?? In 2 and 3? Do you mean at least exists in 2 tables and at least exists for 1 tables??

Comment: They are just email addresses. I just need to know which emails exist in 3 tables, which exist in 2 tables, and which exist in just 1 table. Don't think the actual data matters.

Comment: @lc - not just `a`. I'm interested in `foo`, whichever table it exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `FOO` is unique,

**For No. 1,**

```
SELECT Foo
FROM
    (
        SELECT Foo FROM table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Foo FROM table2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Foo FROM table3
    ) a
GROUP BY Foo
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

**For No. 2,**

```
SELECT Foo
FROM
    (
        SELECT Foo FROM table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Foo FROM table2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Foo FROM table3
    ) a
GROUP BY Foo
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

**For No. 3,**

```
SELECT Foo
FROM
    (
        SELECT Foo FROM table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Foo FROM table2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Foo FROM table3
    ) a
GROUP BY Foo
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: +1 - For 1, just `INNER JOIN` the three tables will be easier.

Comment: @john - I added the number of records for each query. It did not total the number of records from table1, table2, and table3. Something wrong??

Comment: you mean you did not add this line `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`?

Comment: table1, table2, and table3 have 32880, 40721 and 37529 records respectively. When I did the queries, `COUNT(*) = 1` returned 22463 records. `COUNT(*) = 2` returned 16414 records. `COUNT(*) = 3` returned 18568 records. They don't add up; I think they should. Right?

Comment: you did not mention to add them up. I am not confused on what you want. Can you give sample data with desired output? :D please.

Comment: Actually, since the `foo` possibly exist in multiple tables, then I shouldn't expect the results of the queries to match the number of records in the 3 tables. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
If the value of `Cont` is 1 then the value exists in only one table, if the value is 2 then it exists in two tables etc.

```
SELECT foo, COUNT(1) Cont
  FROM 
  (
  SELECT foo
    FROM  a
    UNION
  SELECT foo
    FROM  b
    UNION
 SELECT foo
    FROM  c 
  ) a
  GROUP BY foo
  --   HAVING COUNT(1) = 1 -- 2 FOR EXISTING IN TWO TABLES, 3 FOR EXISTING IN ALL TABLES
```

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie All three. The `cont` column should contain the number of occurences

Comment: @Kickstart Yes, since OP mentioned foo is unique UNION ALL would be a better choice. Didn't notice the unique part while drafting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a single piece of SQL that can get all items with the counts, or (using a HAVING clause) any individual ones if required:-

```
SELECT a.foo, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT foo
FROM  a
UNION
SELECT foo
FROM  b
UNION
SELECT foo
FROM  c) AS z
LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.foo = z.foo
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.foo = z.foo
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON c.foo = z.foo
GROUP BY z.foo
```